# stopping threads gracefully

Tags: java, multithreading, jboss, scheduled-tasks

I am using ScheduledExecutorService for scheduling a thread. I wonder what happens when JBoss is shut down? Does it kill all the threads that are started within the server, including the the one I scheduled? Do I have to do it manually using ScheduledFuture, and cancel the thread when ServletContext is destroyed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods:

- java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService.shutdown()
- java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService.shutdownNow()

JBoss won't call any of these unless you do it in method which will be called upon shutdown. For web applications you have the chance to do it in `javax.servlet.ServletContextListener.contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent)`.

Of course this is the JavaEE/Servlets way. You can hide it by using e.g. Spring Framework. By creating org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler you'll get shutting down for free (this class implements `org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean`). See the details [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html).